# How to Echo query result with single field

Tags: php, mysqli

Please help. I need to print result of this query but nothing appears

```
$fetch_a = "
            SELECT
              programs.Program_Description
            FROM
              programs
            WHERE
              programs.Programid = 
                ('
                   SELECT
                     memberprogram.Programid
                   FROM
                     memberprogram
                   WHERE
                     memberprogram.Memberid = $Memberid && 
                     memberprogram.Option_No = 'Option A'
                  ')
             ";

$result_a = mysqli_query($dbc, $fetch_a);

echo $result_a;
```

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to see what goes wrong in the query - the double `''` is likely to be breaking the query. Note however that the mysql_* library is depreacted and should not be used for new projects.

Comment: "nothing appears" is not clear enough. Do you get a blank screen? Other things are echoed out but no results from this?

Comment: @James Other things are echoing except this one

Comment: what print_r($result_a) returns

Comment: First thing I'd do is remove the single-quotes around your entire sub-query and use `AND` instead of `&&`

Comment: @BushraKhan: did you do what Pekka suggested? You cannot guess what mysql is doing, even if it works as intended you should be checking and catching potential issues.

Comment: @Pekka웃  **mysqli**_query($dbc, $fetch_a);, Pretty sure he's using MySQLi

Comment: One possibility is that the subselect returns more than one row or no row at all. Anyway you better should use a JOIN rather than a subselect in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fetch_row or fetch_array first

[mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)
example:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_a))
echo $row[0]."<br/>";
```

EDIT:
as far as the query is concerned:

- use "WHERE programs.Programid IN" instead of "WHERE programs.Programid ="
- remove the apostrophes
- replace && with AND

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing is your query is a mess. Without knowing the details of your schema design, I'd take a guess with this

```
// note I'm using HEREDOC format
$sql = <<<_SQL
SELECT p.Program_Description
FROM programs p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM memberprogram m
    WHERE m.Option_No = 'Option A'
    AND m.Memberid = ?
    AND m.Programid = p.Programid
)
_SQL;
```

Then, you should really be using parameter binding with a prepared statement. For example

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $Memberid); // assuming $Memberid is an integer
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($programDescription);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo $programDescription;
```